# FileObserver иногда не работает

Tags: java, android, файлы

Метод `OnEvent` иногда вызывается, а иногда и не вызывается.

Должен был вызываться в тех случаях, когда пользователь снял фотографию на свою камеру, и она попадает в папку `/DCIM/Camera/`

Создан следующий класс `MediaListenerService`:

```
public class MediaListenerService extends Service {

    private static FileObserver observer;

    public MediaListenerService() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        startWatching();
    }

    private void startWatching() {

        //The desired path to watch or monitor
        //E.g Camera folder
        final String pathToWatch = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/DCIM/Camera/";
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started and trying to watch " + pathToWatch, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        observer = new FileObserver(pathToWatch, FileObserver.ALL_EVENTS) { // set up a file observer to watch this directory
            @Override
            public void onEvent(int event, @Nullable String path) {
                doing(pathToWatch+path);
            }
        };
        observer.startWatching();
    }

    void doing(String path){
        Log.d("DEBUG", "Log by influence of file: " + path);
    }
}
```

Его применение:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MediaListenerService.class));
}
```

Метод если и срабатывает, то срабатывает примерно через 20 секунд после сохранения фото. Если фото было сделано несколько, метод сработает (не факт) только для некоторых из них, и, как видно по логам, одновременно для всех фотографий.

К тому же, логгирование показывает, что `onEvent` никогда не вызывается для `event` с кодом `create`. Присутствуют вызовы со следующими кодами:

`1`: `ACCESS` - (Доступ)

`16`: `CLOSE_NOWRITE` - (Закрыт без записи)

`32`: `OPEN` - (Открыт)

Comment: Возможно, нужно редактировать заголовки на более подходящие

Comment: Не разрабатывал под Android, но есть вопрос: Правильно ли создавать каждый раз экземпляр observer в методе startWatching? Может быть его инициализировать один раз в конструкторе?

Comment: @A.Bagryanov , исходя из жизненного цикла приложения, метод `onCreate` вызывается единожды при открытии приложения, поэтому `observer` пересоздаваться не будет: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/images/activity_lifecycle.png
Инициализация в конструкторе приводит приложение к крашу